# Does the Windows Surface RT or Pro (Windows 8) support local encryption of Activesync data?

Tags: encryption, email, mobile, exchange, windows-8

Our company policy is requires the local encryption of data for all email (in case the device is stolen)

- Does the Windows Surface (either version) support local encryption?
- Is the local device information sufficiently protected from offline attacks

Answer (score 2):

The Surface Pro runs Windows 8 Pro and has a TPM, so in theory at least, you should have all the available security features of any Windows 8 laptop, including BitLocker.

Comment: I wonder if this is enforced by the Activesync protocol.  MSFT is notoriously bad at enforcing the Activesync policies published by Exchange (e.g. Almost every Windows phone)

Comment: @makerofthings7 Well, on the Surface Pro you're going to be using Outlook as your Exchange client, and presumably using BitLocker for full-disk-encrypytion, so all data should be fully encrypted.  Think of the device in this case as a laptop, rather than a phone.

Comment: So I wonder if the Activesync policy of "Encryption" will enable Bitlocker.  Also that makes me wonder what will happen to the recovery key, and how that can be integrated into existing Corp. IT controls.

Comment: Outlook will not enforce ActiveSync policies. It is up to you and IT to enforce policies through GPO.